# Ignore insert into select duplicate key error (pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

l would like to know if there is any way to continue insert into select after duplicate key error. meaning:  I would like to disregard the exception and to continue to insert the next record.
I'm familiar with ignore_row_on_dupkey_index but as far as I know, hints are should not be used in Production environment.

Few things:
1.  The query inserts millions of records into an empty table.
2.  I would prefer a good solution with a small effect on the performance.

Thanks,
Alex

An example of code that uses ignore_row_on_dupkey_index:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE customers_2
( customer_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  city varchar2(50)

);

insert into customers_2 values(1,'A','TLV');
insert into customers_2 values(2,'B','TLV');
insert into customers_2 values(2,'C','TLV');
insert into customers_2 values(3,'C','TLV');


SELECT * FROM customers_2

insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(customers, customers_pk) */
into customers select * from customers_2

select * from Customers;
```

Comment: it is working in proc. I cant get what is the problem

Comment: According to ORACLE  Hints have issues and known bugs, therefore it should not be used in production and that's why I'm searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 5):

First, this specific hint `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` is not like the rest of the hints.

The restriction you are mentioning is usually concerned with hints that have to do with performance tuning - and these hints are considered to be the last resort.

I don't think this is a case for the specific hint. (see [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ignore_row_on_dupkey_index.htm), and [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7038986332061))

However, the same result could be achieved with `merge`

```
merge into "customers" a
using
( 
   select * from customers_2
) b 
on (a.customer_id  = b.customer_id)
when not matched then 
  insert (customer_id , customer_name,city)
  values (b.customer_id , b.customer_name, b.city);
```

Also, **another** approach with `LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED` is described in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420461/oracle-insert-all-ignore-duplicates).

Comment: The MERGE is good if you just want it to get on with it and the LOG ERRORS solution is good if you want to know which records failed.

Answer (score 1):

> I know, hints are should not be used in Production environment.

It's advisable, yes, for performance tuning hints. But the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index()` is not like other hints, it has a semantic effect, it actually changes how a query behaves. So if it's an ad-hoc query or you pulling out data from OLTP and loading it into a DWH DB, personally I see nothing wrong with using it. 
But preferred way would be to use `log errors` clause of an insert statement, which allows you actually log "bad" rows so you could expect them later. Here is an example:

```
create table t1(
  c1 number constraint t1_pk primary key
);

-- create errors logging table
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name=>'T1');

-- our query
insert into t1
  select 1
    from dual
   connect by level <= 3
  log errors reject limit unlimited;

  1 row created.

 -- "good rows"
 select *
   from t1

       C1
----------
         1
1 row selected.

-- "bad rows"

column ora_err_mesg$ format a30
column c1 format a10

select ora_err_mesg$
      , c1
  from err$_t1

     ORA_ERR_MESG$                  C1        
------------------------------    ---------
ORA-00001: unique constraint (...   1 
ORA-00001: unique constraint (...   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use bulk collect for high performance and use in built exception for the same.

Please go through the link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html and see for more examples that fits your requirement.

In my experience, it has been 10x or more faster compare to insert one by one.